# Django - Pass a jQuery array as url argument

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have the following script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#continue" ).click(function() {
        var selected = $("#meds").bootgrid("getSelectedRows");
        window.location = "{% url 'meds:prescription' selected %}"
    });
});
```

and this view:

```
class PrescriptionView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'meds/prescription.html'
    context_object_name = 'meds'
    model = Medicament

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Medicament.objects.filter(id__in=self.kwargs['selected'])
```

with this url:

```
url(r'^prescription/(?P<selected>.*)/$', views.PrescriptionView.as_view(), name='prescription')
```

Knowing that selected is an array, for example `[3, 6, 4]` I'm trying to use it to display the objects with the id in that array but for some reason even when the array is full nothing is passed in the url, it just looks like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/prescription//` with an empty page, like the argument didn't pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `selected` variable is parsed as a Django template variable, but actually it's not. It's a JS variable and, thus, it's parsed as an empty string.

There is a workaround, though:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#continue").click(function() {
        var selected = $("#meds").bootgrid("getSelectedRows");
        var url = "{% url 'meds:prescription' 'test' %}";  // 'test' is just a placeholder value
        url = url.replace('test', selected);  // replace 'test' with the 'selected' value
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```